# Why does Bitcoin need to change receiving address for privacy, but not Ethereum?

Tags: wallets, bitcoin, privacy

Exactly as it says in the title. Why is it that, for the sake of privacy, wallets change your Bitcoin receiving address for every transaction, but not for Ethereum. Do they just not care about Ethereum privacy as much as they care about Bitcoin privacy, or are there privacy protections in place for Ethereum that Bitcoin doesn't have? I doubt it's the latter because you can publicly view transactions to Ethereum addresses just like you can with Bitcoin, so why the difference in treatment?

Comment: Also, this one: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70709/in-bitcoin-its-bad-to-reuse-addresses-less-security-as-public-key-has-already?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks for the response, but that doesn't fully answer my question. It tells me that there are no extra privacy or security measures in Ethereum that there aren't on Bitcoin, but it doesn't tell me why the wallets treat them differently when they ARE similar in both privacy and security. Is it just because Bitcoin is more popular?